# Python/Matplotlib Inverse Fill of Polar Plot Polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

Currently I have the following script that generates a polar plot of azimuth/radius data. "R1" is simple a list of values of [azimuth, inclination] derived from a table in ArcGIS.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

for(a,r) in R1:
    angles.append(a)
    radius.append(90-r)
theta = np.radians(angles)
r = radius

ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
ax.plot(theta, r, color='black', ls='-', linewidth=1)
ax.fill(theta,r,'0.75') ## should I use ax.fill_betweenx() ?
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rmax(90)
ax.set_rmin(0)
ax.set_yticks(range(0,90,10))
yLabel=['90','','','60','','','30','','','']
ax.set_yticklabels(yLabel)
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

At the moment this creates the following plot:

[image]

How can I "invert" the fill so that what is filled with gray will be white, and what is white will be gray?

I have tried ax.fill_betweenx(theta,90,r,color='0.75') and that didn't work. I have been battling with this for some time now to no avail.

ANY help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

If there is any way I can make this clearer, please let me know in the comments.

Comment: Depending on what else you are doing with this, make the background patch gray and the fill white.

Comment: And it is best to use synthetic data, you could have demonstrated this with `theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)` and `r = 2 + np.sin(theta)`

Comment: Also, using `set_yticklabels` is dangerous and should be avoided.

Comment: @tcaswell: Instead of set_yticklabels, what would you recommend? I'll keep the data referencing in mind for the future too. Still a n00b with matplotlib. Thanks!

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but I think that something like using a function formatter sets the label to be (r - 90) which is a little wonky, but less so that using `set_yticklabels`.  To see the danger, change your r limits or tick locations.  The labels will be completely de-coupled from the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with this later, the quickest way is to simply make the background gray and the fill white:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
r = 2 + np.sin(theta * 2)
ax.patch.set_facecolor('0.5')
ax.plot(theta, r, color='black', ls='-', linewidth=1)
ax.fill(theta,r,'w')
plt.show()
plt.draw() # just to be safe!
```

Comment: Worked great... I like the look of how it turned out. Thanks!